# Proper comma usage for multiple city/country pairs

Tags: commas

I want to write a sentence with three city/county pairs.  I normally use a comma between a city/country like so:

> I live in Sydney, Australia.

But what is proper when describing three places?  I want to separate the city/country with a comma and then another comma between each pair, but it looks wrong.

> I have lived in Sydney, Australia, Tokyo, Japan and Paris, France.

Comment: It's a valid question but I'm pretty sure everyone knows where those cities are.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a comma to separate the cities from the countries, and a semicolon to separate the locations. See the example of the semicolon being used as a super-comma given [at this *The Oatmeal* comic](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon):

> I have lived in Sydney, Australia; Tokyo, Japan; and Paris, France.

Note that the list ends with "Paris, France". Even if the sentence continues after the list, there should be no further list-related punctuation. For example:

> I have lived in Sydney, Australia; Tokyo, Japan; and Paris, France at various times.