# Do you always need commas after dialogue tags and detailed locations?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dialogue

I have a couple of questions about commas.

1. If you quote a short sentence, can you omit the comma after the dialogue tag as a matter of style?

   For instance:

   > Whenever I come home, I always say "Honey, I'm home!"

   Is the comma after "say" in this sentence essential? I like the way it reads without it.
2. When you have a modifying phrase after a location within a location, do you need to use a comma?

   For instance:

   > I visited Tokyo, Japan last summer.

   I have seen some sources say this version is correct, while others have said I need a comma after "Japan."

Comment: This question is actually better suited to [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). For instance, look at [Dialog, just what's the best way to write it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/dialog-just-whats-the-best-way-to-write-it). Or an external reference like [How to Punctuate Dialogue](http://theeditorsblog.net/2010/12/08/punctuation-in-dialogue/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a comma needed before quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146173/is-there-a-comma-needed-before-quotation)

Comment: And this your second? [Proper comma usage ... city-country pairs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225012/proper-comma-usage-for-multiple-city-country-pairs) Or this? [Should I put a comma after a state and before a country](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312239/should-i-put-a-comma-after-a-state-before-a-country)

Answer (score -1):

The following is is quoted from the wikiHow article ["How to Use Quotation Marks"](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Quotation-Marks)

> Put quotation marks around the dialogue only. Quotation marks are essential for notating dialogue, as they signal to the reader the words are being spoken.
> For example:
>
> - “Where is my cat?” the woman screamed.
> - I demanded, “Let me see her.”

Take a look at the last rule at the link below, if the link provided earlier was not enough to prove my point, though it should have been. A country's name is even more obvious than the name of a state, which makes the case for the comma in the sentence in question even stronger: https://grammartips.homestead.com/placecommas.html

The idea of replacing "Tokyo" with "doctor" is absurd. Tokyo is a city, a geographical location, and the rules of geographical location apply to it.

Comment: OP does not ask about quotation marks, but about the comma (/colon /zero punctuation) often used in addition to the inverted commas.